# Your Xcode does not support macOS 11. Installing mongodb-community Via Brew

Tags: mongodb, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to setup MongoDb Locally on a MacOs BigSur and I'm getting this error "Error: Your Xcode does not support macOS 11." It suggested that "Please update your Xcode or delete it if no updates are available." as at now I'm sure that can't be the only solution as I'm running Xcode 12.0.1 and getting the latest one is not an option for now.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this is that I installed Xcode CommanLine 12.3.0
I'm not sure if this is a good idea since I'm running Xcode 12.0.1 for now but it does work fine.
I installed this via the Software Update Section on MacOS preference so I want to believe that it wouldn't have suggested it if it's a bad idea.
Hopefully someone fine this useful.